# Disable MatRipple in Child Components

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a child component called "text-message" that is shared with several parent components.  It uses a "matRipple" effect.  I need this effect on every parent except for one named "group-message".  In the `text-message.component.ts` file the following code exists:

```
@ViewChild(MatRipple, { static: true }) ripple: MatRipple;

  launchRipple() {
    this.ripple.launch({
      persistent: false,
      centered: true,
      animation: { enterDuration: 1000, exitDuration: 1200 },
      color: 'rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.15)'
    });
  }
```

On the text-message.component.html is:

```
<div matRipple class="text-message" [ngClass]="{'unread': !message?.tmsRead}" appDblClick
  (dblclick)="onClick($event)">
```

The child component looks like this in the parent:

```
<text-message [message]="message" [timeOffset]="currentSiteTimeOffset$ | async" [showStatus]="false"></text-message>
```

I need to turn this off if it is in the "group-message.component.html".  Is this possible?  I tried this:

```
<text-message [message]="message" [timeOffset]="currentSiteTimeOffset$ | async" [showStatus]="false" [disableRipple]="true" ></text-message>
```

But I receive an error "can't bind to 'disableRipple"' since it isn't a known property of 'text-message'".

I also tried this in the group-message.component.ts:

```
  @ViewChildren(MatRipple) ripple : MatRipple;
 this.ripple.disabled;
```

I am very new to Angular and am still learning how to work with parents, children, and siblings.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not have an input on the child component to include ripple or not? have the default to include ripple, and only in the specific parent, set it to be disabled. won't work for you?

Comment: Maybe, How would I do that?  The first div in the child component is matRiplle.  Are you saying remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of properties of [MatRipple directive](https://material.angular.io/components/ripple/api#MatRipple) is

```
@Input('matRippleDisabled')
disabled: boolean
```

We can make a use of it by adding an input to the text-message.component.html

```
<div matRipple class="text-message" [ngClass]="{'unread': !message?.tmsRead}" appDblClick
  (dblclick)="onClick($event)" [matRippleDisabled]="disableRipple">
```

Of course the declaration of disableRipple variable is needed in text-message.component.ts. We declare it as @Input, since we want to replace the default value as soon as the new one arrives

```
@Input() disableRipple = false;
```

The next step would be setting a value of disableRipple variable by passing true from parent component.

The group-message.component.html would remain like this

```
<text-message [message]="message" [timeOffset]="currentSiteTimeOffset$ | async" [showStatus]="false" [disableRipple]="true" ></text-message>
```